# Assembly: How to edit a string before print it

Tags: assembly, x86

I write this simple code to try to modify a string before print it:

```
    .data 

    stringaOut:         .ascii "000000\n"
    stringaOut_len:     .long - stringaOut

    .text               
        .global main

    main:

        leal stringaOut, %esi
        movl $49, 0(%esi)
        movl $49, 1(%esi)
        movl $49, 2(%esi)
        movl $49, 3(%esi)
        movl $49, 4(%esi)
        movl $49, 5(%esi)
        movl $49, 6(%esi)

        movl $4, %eax
        movl $1, %ebx
        leal stringaOut, %ecx
        movl stringaOut_len, %edx
        int $0x80

        #return 0
        movl $1, %eax
        movl $0, %ebx
        int $0x80
```

I think it should change the zeros in the string with 1, but why doesn't it print anything?

Comment: It does print ones here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movl` moves a **l**ong integer (32-bit). What you want is `movb` which moves a single **b**yte (8-bit). Otherwise, each assignment overrides the next 3 characters unnecessarily.

Comment: While that is true, it's not really relevant (except for overwriting the final end of line). It should, and does, still print `1111111`

Comment: @Jester I couldn't see anything else wrong with it. It may be that OP's machine only prints once it hits a newline character or something to do with words needing to be 4byte aligned.

Comment: Ahha, you are right, that is a problem, because it not only overwrites the end of line, it's also overwriting the length stored in memory directly after the string.

Comment: @cdo256 I try with movb, but it doesn't print anything

Comment: You also have a typo `.long - stringaOut` should be `.long . - stringaOut` (notice the dot before the minus)

Comment: Thank you all! :)